# Docker - Bash: IP: command not found

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm currently trying to set up a hyperledger fabric network using docker toolbox, based on the guide [HERE](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Network-setup.html?cm_mc_uid=81974749078914879942140&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1488939665#starting-up-validating-peers)

When it comes to "Starting up validating peers" step, I followed and entered `ip add` into the terminal, but it returns `bash: ip: command not found`. Any solution? I've tried `ifconfig` as well and it's the same issue, command not found.

Using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your runtime environment? Is this Docker for Windows (in which case it's virtualizing a real Linux guest), or is it the Windows Subsystem for Linux (in which case it's not)?

Comment: It's not Docker for Windows, which requires Windows 10 Pro that uses HyperV. Mine was installed using Docker Toolbox, the legacy installer using Virtualbox before they moved to HyperV.

I entered the command into Docker Quickstart Terminal, which if I'm not mistaken is virtualizing a Linux guest.

Comment: That's a linux command, run a `docker-machine ssh` to get to the embedded VM.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am also at docker toolbox windows, and as in this question doesn't not seem to be replies regarding the question docker toolbox on windows, but running into embedded VM docker-machine ssh, there is a command IP, but  there are not package managers yum and apt, as I seem to miss other packages-not the IP, so I guess, I will have to use Ubuntu windows subsystem, which is as far as I know not available at Home version

Answer (score 124):

Install `ip` command package for Ubuntu.

```
apt update
apt install iproute2
```

Comment: For centos, use `ifconfig`

Comment: Please stop recommending people update before running commands.

Comment: @Owl `apt update` updates the package list, it doesn't actually update the system. This is necessary on some fresh installs, especially when using Docker.

Answer (score 26):

I have tried `hostname -I`. Working fine for me. No need to install a new package.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, your link has been broken (or it might be inaccessible from Iran). Although there is not enough evidence of which Linux OS you are trying to use, a solution is provided as follow work under **.deb** (e.g. Ubuntu) and **.rpm** (e.g. Fedora) package managers.

At first, update the container's repository:
Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
```

CentOS:

```
yum update
```

Fedora:

```
dnf update
```

Secondly, install net-tools package.
Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install net-tools
```

CentOS:

```
yum install net-tools
```

Fedora:

```
dnf install net-tools
```

Lately, **ifconfig** has been replaced with **ip** command. So make sure to check both commands, some Linux distributions have not changed the command yet.

Comment: Adding to @Esmaeil answer, **yum install net-tools** gets **ifconfig** working. In case you want **ip** command to work as well, you'll need to download iproute package by running **yum install iproute**

Comment: and iproute2 for debian

Answer (score 7):

for command `ip` not found in centos 7, you can use `yum install iproute -y` to fix.

for command `ifconfig` not found in centos 7, you can use `yum install net-tools -y` to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Although OP was on Windows 10. I landed on this question searching for a fix for macOS and didn't find [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/898971/290915) for a while. So I'm linking it here as well just in case

You can install `ip` tool on OS X via brew:

```
brew install iproute2mac
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't work.

Do `docker ps` or `docker images` in GitBash to see if the docker containers and images are running.

I recommend installing Docker Community Edition if you are running Win 10. Make sure u have Hyper-V enabled.